# Scala method that takes a function as a parameter and then executes it

Tags: scala

I want to write a simple method that takes a function as a parameter and then executes it.

```
def exec(f: (a:Int, b:Int) => Boolean): Boolean = f(a,b)
```

I'm not sure what is wrong with the above, but I get the error:

```
<console>:1: error: ')' expected but ':' found.
```

Answer (score 8):

```
def exec(f: (a:Int, b:Int) => Boolean): Boolean = f(a,b)
              ^      ^
              |      |
//   These are supposed to be types, but a: Int and b: Int aren't types,
//   they are identifiers with type ascriptions.
```

It should look a little more like:

```
def exec(f: (Int, Int) => Boolean): Boolean = f(a, b)
```

Now `f` is a function `(Int, Int) => Boolean`. But this doesn't compile, because `a` and `b` are not defined.

You either need to pass them in, or fix them to a value.

```
def exec(a: Int, b: Int)(f: (Int, Int) => Boolean): Boolean = f(a, b)

scala> exec(2, 3)(_ > _)
res1: Boolean = false
```

Comment: So you have to make it a partial function?  That doesn't look clean is there another way?

Comment: There is no partial function here. The arguments are curried, but they don't have to be. It's not clear what you actually want to do with this. `a` and `b` can't be magically materialized from nothing.

Comment: @Blankman are you just trying to delay evaluation of a function?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute a function with parameters in your `exec` method you need to:

```
scala> def exec(f: => Unit) = {
     | println("Exec:")
     | f
     | }
scala> def foo(f : (Int, Int)): Unit = println(f._1 + f._2)
scala> exec(foo((3, 4)))
Exec:
7
```

because `foo((3, 4))` type is `=> Unit`

Answer (score 0):

Not quite an answer to your original question (and too big to be a comment), but if you're looking to write a tasteful, nice-looking execution operator and don't particularly like the syntax of the provided answers, perhaps something similar to `scalaz`'s pipe operator (`|>`) might be what you're thinking of?

```
scala> // You could just get this from scalaz with import scalaz._ and import Scalaz._

scala> implicit class FancyExec[A](x: A){def |>[B](f: A => B) = f(x)}

scala> 5 |> (_ + 6)
res1: Int = 11

scala> (5, 4) |> ((_: Int) < (_: Int)).tupled
res2: Boolean = false

scala> val f = ((_: Int) < (_: Int)).tupled
f: ((Int, Int)) => Boolean = <function1>

scala> val g = ((_: Int) > (_: Int)).tupled
g: ((Int, Int)) => Boolean = <function1>

scala> List(f, g) map ((5, 4) |> _)
res3: List[Boolean] = List(false, true)
```